# Error in a simple selenium script

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried the same kind of script using a day before using the same chromedriver path it executed then, but today when I tried another script using the path I am getting the error.

```
package ScriptsSelenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class TextBox_EntData {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Sneha\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("XXX@YYail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
```

Here is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
    at ScriptsSelenium.TextBox_EntData.main(TextBox_EntData.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

only thing you need to change in your code is your `chromedriver.exe` path statement execution. You need to call it before you initiate a new `chromedriver`.
Just change

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Sneha\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: If it is not corrected when i execute it, it will show error. How can i proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have the chromedriver.exe file at the specified path and use the below configuration for Chrome.

The `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOptions` class basically allow you to set some options for your browser (like starting a maximized browser, setting the chromedriver path and so on).

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//this statement will not show any warnings when you launch chrome
options.addArguments("test-type");
//start a maximized window 
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
//this allows you to use a user profile
//options.addArguments("user-data-dir=D:/temp/");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","res/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: The path is correct as i used the same path for the previous script. I am a beginner in selenium. So can you please elaborate your answer?. What the above code says?